# Blank page on startup and cannot find module webpack in Jhipster app

Tags: maven, npm, webpack, jhipster, yarnpkg

I generated a jhipster app, when I run the mvn command it starts up with no exceptions or errors but when I go to the localhost:8080 I get a blank page.

When I try to run “yarn start” I get an error :

```
cannot find module webpack.
```

I’ve run the command:

```
npm install
```

and

```
npm install —save-dev  webpack
```

But I still get the same error.

Comment: Please don't mix yarn and npm, this is a recipe for failure. In dev, you're supposed to go to localhost:9000 to access UI not 8080, see doc. Everything should work out of the box, if it does not it's either your environment is wrong or you overlooked some error. What is your node version?

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate. Does following answer solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062717/application-generated-with-jhipster-4-returning-blank-page-on-8080-but-not-on-9/45200847#45200847

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application generated with JHipster 4 returning blank page on 8080, but not on 9000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062717/application-generated-with-jhipster-4-returning-blank-page-on-8080-but-not-on-9)