# npm equivalent to yarn install and yarn webpack:build

Tags: angular, npm, jhipster, node-modules, yarnpkg

Jhipster's http://www.jhipster.tech/installation/ allow to use either yarn or npm , on a different question [Application generated with JHipster 4 returning blank page on 8080, but not on 9000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062717/application-generated-with-jhipster-4-returning-blank-page-on-8080-but-not-on-9/47382564) 
It is suggested to run yarn install and yarn webpack:build
I am new to UI development and we are only allowed npm, so I want to know what will be the equivalent of **yarn install**  and **yarn webpack:build**

I generated a new project with

D:\rajblog>jhipster --npm
Using JHipster version installed globally
Running default command
Executing jhipster:app
Options: npm: true

( not with "yo jhipster --npm"), it automatically called "npm install" , but when I run "npm webpack:build" , *it does not run* and I get

D:\rajblog>npm webpack:build

Usage: npm

where  is one of:

and

D:\rajblog>npm webpack-build

Usage: npm

where  is one of:
    access, adduser, bin, bugs, c, cache, completion, config,
    ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor, edit,
    explore, get, help, help-search, i, init, install,
    install-test, it, link, list, ln, login, logout, ls,
    outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix, profile, prune,
    publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root, run, run-script,
    s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star, stars, start, stop, t,
    team, test, token, tst, un, uninstall, unpublish, unstar,
    up, update, v, version, view, whoami

npm  -h     quick help on 
npm -l           display full usage info
npm help   search for help on 
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\XXUid.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm  --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@5.5.1 D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm

Answer (score 2):

You could see defined scripts in your `package.json` file, for example:

```
"scripts": {
  "cleanup": "rimraf build/{aot,www}",
  "build": "yarn run webpack:prod",
  …
  "webpack:build:main": "yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
  "webpack:build": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:build:main",
  …
  "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
```

Based on this you could start webpack with following `npm run` command:

```
npm run cleanup && npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile
```

Select script you want to use, e.g. `webpack/webpack.dev.js` or `webpack/webpack.prod.js`

Second approach would be to install webpack globally

```
npm install --global webpack
```

Run script as

```
webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.js
```

Answer (score 0):

To use npm, you need to generate your project with --npm flag: `jhipster --npm`

Then, the commands are similar:
`npm install` and `npm webpack:build`